# top tab navigation wix react native navigation app is getting crashed

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using wix React Native Navigation version **4.8.1**. I am trying to implement topTabs but android app is getting crashed. I am using the following configuration as suggested by other stackoverflow answers. But when I check Options.d.ts in node_modules, I can't see any **topTab** property inside **Options** object which is odd. Is there something I am missing or TopTabs layout should be used with other property. I am not able to get any proper documentation from WIX's site so posting my question here.

Navigation.setRoot({
   root: {

```
  topTabs: {
    id: 'BottomTabsId',
    children: [
      {
        component: {
          name: 'SignIn',
          options: {
            topTab: {
              title: 'Tab 1',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        component: {
          name: 'SignUp',
          options: {
            topTab: {
              title: 'Tab 2',
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
},
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Top tabs navigation is not supported in react-native-navigation by wix, current latest version at the time of answer is v.7.0.0. They may support top tabs navigation in future.